# create RAM disk as early in boot process as possible

Tags: startup, launchd, cron

I am attempting to to **create a RAM disk as early as possible in the boot process** so that my copy of Stata can use it to store temporary files. According to the instructions from Stata one can set the STATATMP variable within the user's environment files (in my case **.zshenv** which contains the line `export STATATMP="/Volumes/Stata_RAM_Disk"`) however even when I create the RAM disk *before* launching my copy of Stata, it won't be recognized. As far as I can tell the RAM disk needs to exist earlier in the boot process to make this work. I've tried using a `crontab`:

```
@reboot diskutil erasevolume HFS+ Stata_RAM_Disk $(hdiutil attach -nomount ram://524288)
```

Which does not succeed in creating the disk. I've also tried a LaunchAgent plist `com.stataramdisk.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.stataramdisk</string>

  <key>UserName</key>
  <string>root</string>

  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/path/to/stataramdisk.sh</string>
  </array>

  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>

  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/stata_ram_disk.err</string>

  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/stata_ram_disk.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

which I load using:

```
cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
sudo chown root:wheel com.stataramdisk.plist
sudo launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.stataramdisk.plist
```

the contents of the `stataramdisk.sh` file are:

```
sleep 10
diskutil erasevolume HFS+ "Stata_RAM_Disk_256" $(hdiutil attach -nomount ram://524288)
```

however this also does not create the RAM disk. (I've also tried without the `sleep` line). The log files `/tmp/stata_ram_disk.out` and `/tmp/stata_ram_disk.err` are also not created. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? It seems a few of you have had this problem in the past, and I've referenced these posts looking for a solution:

[Mount a RAM disk on boot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50510/mount-a-ram-disk-on-boot)

[How to mount a RAM disk on startup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/how-to-mount-a-ram-disk-on-startup)

Comment: If you run your script manually, does it create the disk? If you start via crontab and redirect stdout/stderr of the script to a file, what does the file contain?

Comment: Also, considering that Strata doesn't recognize the ramdisk even if you create it manually before starting the application, are you sure we focus on the right problem here?

Comment: @nohillside. Yes, the script itself works and creates the RAM disk. I have not tried redirecting via `crontab` but I will try that now. Ignore the part about Stata as I'm interested in achieving this for other reasons as well.

Comment: @nohillside What is the best way to do this redirection? For the `crontab` can I just do `2> stderr_file.txt 1> stdout_file.txt`? But isn't using `LaunchAgent` the preferred method of achieving such things at boot?

Comment: I would add a full path, e.g. `> /tmp/ramdisk.log 2>&1`.  But your launchd.plist already should write a log, is there anything relevant in there? Or in `system.log` about any problems in running the agent?

Comment: @nohillside I can't seem to find anything in `system.log` regarding this, but I will try both the `crontab` and `LaunchAgent` again attempting redirection.

Comment: Is there anything in /tmp/stata_ram_disk.err, or /tmp/stata_ram_disk.out ?

Comment: @nohillside Sorry, it took a little while before I could restart. I tried redirecting stderr and stdout with the `crontab` but nothing appears. As for the `LaunchAgent`, the two files appear in `/tmp` but they are both empty.